# Could it be that users are added/removed in the background from /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

```
from pwd import getpwuid
getpwuid(48).pw_name
```

This Python program prints `apache` 99% of the time. 48 is the id that appears in `/etc/passwd` for the apache user. Without any apparent reason, Python sometimes prints the error:

```
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 48'
```

I need to understand why this happen sometimes. Can the apache user be removed from the file for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the CPython 2.7 source code for the `pwd` module, particularly the getpwuid() call: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/pwdmodule.c#L114  It looks like a wrapper around the system `getpwuid` call with not very much code - Python doesn't read from /etc/passwd directly.

Here's a current Ubuntu manpage (you didn't mention any particular OS) for (3) getpwuid: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man3/getpwuid.3posix.html which includes:

> **ERRORS**
>
> The getpwuid() and getpwuid_r() functions may fail if:
>
> ```
>    EIO    An I/O error has occurred.
>
>    EINTR  A signal was caught during getpwuid().
>
>    EMFILE {OPEN_MAX} file descriptors are currently open  in  the  calling
>           process.
>
>    ENFILE The  maximum  allowable number of files is currently open in the
>           system.
> ```

Since you haven't mentioned any user management processes which might be regenerating your user accounts, I'm going to answer that no, apache doesn't get removed from /etc/passwd, but your webserver does hit some heavy IO or too many open files condition where reading /etc/passwd becomes impossible.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a very interesting phenomenon (and a great question) but I doubt that Apache is being removed from your `/etc/passwd` file.

On a GNU/Linux system, there are a number of different authentication mechanisms that can be used. In modern systems, the [Name Service Switch (NSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) is used to resolve user names and IDs. This is configured in the `passwd` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, e.g., the following configuration means that the `/etc/passwd` will be searched first and if the user or ID is not found, then a configured NIS server is used to determine the user name/ID.

```
passwd:     files nis
```

However, in some systems, the NSS library functions might not actually be used to resolve a name request.  Some systems may have a service such as `nscd` running. This is a daemon that caches name service requests, e.g., if the Apache user had previously been looked up, its name would be stored in the `nscd` cache and it would return the correct name or ID without `/etc/passwd` being searched.

### Debugging

I would try debugging this issue by running the Python program through `strace`. At the very end of the output file, you should see the system calls that are used to retrieve the name of the user.

```
strace -o getpwuid_test.trace  getpwuid_test.py
```

You would need to run this command enough times to catch the call to `getpwuid` failing to see why it failed. I, for one, would be interested to see the results.

#### Examples

Here’s an example of the output where no caching daemon is running and NSS is used to read the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1717, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7fa9000
read(3, "#\n# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# An ex"..., 4096) = 1717
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
...
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY)           = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFD)                     = 0
fcntl64(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3012, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7fa9000
read(3, "root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash\n"..., 4096) = 3012
close(3)                                = 0
...
write(1, "apache\n", 7)
```

Here’s an example where the `nscd` service is running and the NSS library is bypassed:

```
socket(PF_FILE, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"...}, 110) = 0
send(3, "\2\0\0\0\v\0\0\0\7\0\0\0passwd\0", 19, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 19
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 5000) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
recvmsg(3, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(2)=[{"passwd\0", 7}, {"\270O\3\0\0\0\0\0", 8}], msg_controllen=16, {cmsg_len=16, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, {4}}, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 15
...
write(1, "apache\n", 7)
```